# Issues with GridBagLayout: TextArea overlapping MenuBar

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Hello i am having trouble with application. The panel holding the JTextArea is overlapping the panel containing the menuBar. I want to customize my GUI app but having trouble fixing the overlap. Below is my code: I imported all the apis needed.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ClientPanels extends JPanel{

private JMenu fileM, editM, styleM;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JMenuBar menuBar;
private JScrollPane scpane;
private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel panel2;
private JMenuItem aboutI, openI, saveI, cutI, copyI, pasteI,  exitI;
private GridBagConstraints g;

public ClientPanels() {
    initialize();
}

 private void initialize(){
//initializing and setting up my data
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    textArea2 = new JTextArea(40, 50);
    JScrollPane scpane = new JScrollPane(textArea2);
    panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    //menuitems
    openI = new JMenuItem("Open");
    saveI = new JMenuItem("Save");
    exitI = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    copyI = new JMenuItem("Copy");
    pasteI = new JMenuItem("Paste");
    aboutI = new JMenuItem("About");

    fileM = new JMenu("File");
    editM = new JMenu("Edit");
    styleM = new JMenu("Style");

    fileM.add(openI);
    fileM.add(saveI);
    fileM.add(aboutI);
    fileM.add(exitI);

    editM.add(copyI);
    editM.add(pasteI);

    //adding the menu to the menuBars
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(fileM);
    menuBar.add(editM);
    menuBar.add(styleM);

    panel1.add(menuBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel2.add(scpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    //adding the sub-panels to the main panel
    addComp(panel1,0,0,0.5,0.0,0,0,GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST,GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
    addComp(panel2,4,1,3,10,0,10, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE);

}
//adding components to panel using GridBagLayout as the layout manager
 private void addComp(JPanel panel, int Xpos, int Ypos, double wx,double wy,
                    int compWidth, int compHeight, int place, int stretch)
 {
    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
    g.gridx = Xpos;
    g.gridy = Ypos;
    g.weightx = wx;
    g.weighty= wy;
    g.gridwidth = compWidth;
    g.gridheight = compHeight;
    g.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    g.anchor = place;
    g.fill = stretch;

    add(panel, g);
 }

}
```

main method:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


 public class TestJavaClient {
    private ClientPanels panels;
     public TestJavaClient()
  { 
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      panels = new ClientPanels();

     frame.setSize(800,590);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     frame.add(panels);
     frame.pack();
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setVisible(true);

  }

public static void main(String[] args) {


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
            new TestJavaClient();
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Take a read through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and understand what it means by *Minimal* and *Complete* (and compliable)...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i apologize for the long read. I re-edited my code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The java guy displayed the menu bar ok. But i when added JTextArea it was overlapping the menuBar. Basically writing over the menubar and hiding the menu items

Comment: It still won't compile...

Comment: Don't mess with the `gridwidth`/`gridheight` values unless you know what they actually do.

Comment: @MadProgrammer i fixed the errors when u mentioned it did not compile. But it still overlaps the menu bar

Comment: Make `gridwidth` and `gridheight` equal to `1`, change the `gridx` for the text area to `0`, it'll work...not sure why you're trying to use `GridBagLayout` for this, but that's just me...

Comment: @MadProgrammer wanted to learn how to customize panels using GridBagLayout.

Comment: @MadProgrammer your proposal worked as it was not overlapping anymore. So if i wanted to place a panel below the JTextArea will i take the same approach.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so much. I was able to add another panel with a similar approach. Basically i did a FlowLayout and just incremented the gridwidth and gridheight both 2.

Comment: Do you actually understand what `gridwidth` and `gridheight` do?  The `gridy` was probably all you needed to increment...

Comment: @MadProgrammer isn't it the number of cells the components uses? or am i wrong

Comment: More or less, it's the number of cells that the component can expand across, from it's current `gridx/y` position, but this doesn't mean you can't add other components to the cells these other components cover...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats why we had to move to the next row right that is not used up?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
panel1.add(menuBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

To something like (you'll need to refactor the code):

```
frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

But as mentioned in a comment, an MCVE would get better answers.

Comment: because i was extending from my class was extending from JPanel. I had to add to the panel1 and finally add it to the main panel. In my test class it was added to the frame.

Comment: Why is there still no MCVE?  An MCVE needs to be one source file - demote `ClientPanels` from public to default access and paste it into the end of the source with `main(String[])`. Then consolidate the imports.  BTW - I don't really see a reason to extend `JPanel` here.

Comment: i was learning java swing and practicing just extending the JPanel

Comment: *"practicing just extending the JPanel"*  I'd recommend practicing ***not*** extending panel, since that is what we should be doing when not changing or adding functionality (i.e. 99.9% of the time).